What is the proper way of using <Picker.Behavior> in MAUI?
so this is kind of going to be a 2 for 1 question since they're a little bit related but if that's a problem then we can just focus on the first problem. Also im relatively new to MAUI so please bear with me.
Problem no 1:
I've been trying to implement a Behavior for a Picker control that makes the Border color and Label color Red when a certain condition is met (in this case the condition is wether the user has selected something or not), but i just can't seem to make it work. First i made a Behavior for an Entry Control which worked perfectly, here's how i did it:
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InvalidBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource GreyBorderBrush}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidationBehavior}, Path=IsValid}"
                TargetType="Border"
                Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource InvalidRed}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="InvalidLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#aeb1b6" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidationBehavior}, Path=IsValid}"
                TargetType="Label"
                Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource InvalidRed}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<Label
    Padding="2,10,10,5"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    FontSize="Micro"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
    Style="{StaticResource InvalidLabelStyle}"
    Text="Número do SAV"
    TextColor="#aeb1b6" />
<Border
    Padding="2,2,2,2"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5"
    StrokeThickness="1.2"
    Style="{StaticResource InvalidBorderStyle}">
    <Entry
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        FontSize="Small"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
        IsEnabled="{Binding KeyBoardIsHidden}"
        Keyboard="Numeric"
        MaxLength="8"
        Placeholder="SAV"
        PlaceholderColor="#aeb1b6"
        Text="{Binding EntrySAV}"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:TextValidationBehavior
                x:Name="ValidationBehavior"
                Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
                MinimumLength="8" />
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding GetDataFromSAVCommand}" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
</Border>

and since that worked for Entry i figured it would be similar for a Picker, but i was wrong because the Flag "ValidateOnValueChanged" doesn't seem to trigger when the selecteditem in the picker is changed and that's probably because the parent tag "TextValidationBehavior" doesnt work for Picker. Do you guys have any idea on how i should approach this?
Not sure if showing this helps understanding but the Entry with the behavior that works looks like this and i would like to achieve the same behavior but for the Picker control:

Problem no 2:
As you can see, to use these behaviors in each page i have to add the <contentpage.resources> chunk and that doesn't seem good, i tried adding it in the App.xaml but since the binding is referencing the x:name ValidationBehavior it doesn't work. Any ideas?
If you guys have any question about the code please feel free to ask and i'll try to give as much info as possible
So i tried this for the picker but didnt work, figured adding a property in my viewmodel to notify wether it has a value or not and bind it to the IsValid property could work but no success:
In the ViewModel:
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Navio> _navios;
[ObservableProperty, NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(isNavioValid))]
private Navio _selectedNavio;
public bool isNavioValid => SelectedNavio != null;

In the Xaml

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InvalidBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource GreyBorderBrush}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidationBehavior}, Path=IsValid}"
                TargetType="Border"
                Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource InvalidRed}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="InvalidLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#aeb1b6" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidationBehavior}, Path=IsValid}"
                TargetType="Label"
                Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource InvalidRed}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>




<Label
    Padding="2,10,10,5"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    FontSize="Micro"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
    Style="{StaticResource InvalidLabelStyle}"
    Text="Nome do Navio"
    TextColor="#aeb1b6" />
<Border
    Padding="2,2,2,2"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    Stroke="{StaticResource GreyBorderBrush}"
    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5"
    StrokeThickness="1.2"
    Style="{StaticResource InvalidBorderStyle}">
    <Picker
        Title="Navio"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        FontSize="Small"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Navios}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNavio}"
        TextColor="Black">
        <Picker.ItemDisplayBinding>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                <Binding Path="Viagem" />
                <Binding Path="ShipCode" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Picker.ItemDisplayBinding>
        <Picker.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:TextValidationBehavior
                x:Name="ValidationBehavior"
                Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
                IsValid="{Binding isNavioValid}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
    </Picker>
</Border>


It seems that the ValidateOnValueChanged can't be applied to Picker when the selected item is changed, the official docs also gives an example on Entry not Picker see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/text-validation-behavior#using-the-textvalidationbehavior

Yeah, it seems doing it that way won't work, would you happen to know of another approach to achieve that kind of behavior? I'm out of ideas and haven't been able to find something similar so far :(

You probably can use Triggers to achieve that behavior.
